# javascript hackerranks sherlock and array performance issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

> Watson gives Sherlock an array A of length N. Then he asks him to
>   determine if there exists an element in the array such that the sum of
>   the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its
>   right. If there are no elements to the left/right, then the sum is
>   considered to be zero. Formally, find an i, such that,
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains T, the number of test cases. For each test
>   case, the first line contains N, the number of elements in the array
>   A. The second line for each test case contains N space-separated
>   integers, denoting the array A.
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
> 1<=T<=10
> 1<=N<=10^5
> 1<=Ai<=2*10^4
> 1<=i<=N
> ```
>
> Output Format
>
> For each test case print YES if there exists an element in the array,
>   such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of
>   the elements on its right; otherwise print NO.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2 
> 3
>  1 2 3
>
> 4
>  1 2 3 3
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> NO 
> YES
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> For the first test case, no such index exists. For the second test
>   case,
>
> therefore index 3 satisfies the given conditions.

I'm having timeout issues on 3 of the test cases

```
 function check(input) {
    var result = "NO";
    var sum=0;
    input.map(function(data){
        sum=sum+(+data);
    })
    sumLeft=0;
    sumRight=sum-(+input[0]);

    for(var i=1;i<input.length;i++){
        sumLeft=sumLeft+(+input[i-1]);
        sumRight=sumRight-(+input[i])
        if(sumLeft==sumRight)
        {
            console.log("YES");
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("NO");
}

function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    var lines = input.split("\r\n");
    for (var m = 2; m < lines.length; m = m + 2) {
        check(lines[m].split(" "));
    }
}
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function(input) {
    _input += input;
});
process.stdin.on("end", function() {
    processData(_input);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through the array from both ends in inwards direction using two pointers (indices). Keep a balance, starting with 0, as follows:

When the balance is negative move the left pointer one step to the right while increasing the balance with the value you leave behind. When the balance is positive, move the right pointer one step to the left while decreasing the balance with the value you leave behind.

When the two pointers meet each other, check the balance. If it is zero, you have success.

Here is the algorithm in ES6 code, together with a text area where you can adapt the input according to the required input format:

```js
function hasMiddle(a) {
    var balance = 0, i = 0, j = a.length-1;
    while (i < j) balance += balance > 0 ? -a[j--] : a[i++];
    return !balance;
}

// I/O: event handling, parsing input, formatting output

var input = document.querySelector('textarea');
var output = document.querySelector('pre');

input.oninput = function() {
    var lines = this.value.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/).filter(s => s.trim().length);
    // Strip the case count and array element counts:
    lines = lines.slice(1).filter( (s, i) => i % 2 ); 
    // Call function for each test case, returning array of booleans:
    var results = lines.map( line => hasMiddle(line.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)) );
    // Output results
    output.textContent = results.map( pos => pos ? 'YES' : 'NO' ).join('\n');
}
// Evaluate input immediately
input.oninput();
```

```html
Input:<br>
<textarea style="width:100%; height:120px">2 
3
 1 2 3

4
 1 2 3 3
</textarea>
<pre></pre>
```

This algorithm requires your input array to consist of non-negative numbers.

If you need to support negative numbers in your array, then the algorithm needs to go through the array first to calculate the sum, and then go through the array again to find the point where the balance reaches 0:

```js
function hasMiddle(a) {
    var balance = a.reduce( (sum, v) => sum + v );
    return !a.every ( (v, i) => balance -= v + (i ? a[i-1] : 0) );
}
// I/O for snippet

var input = document.querySelector('textarea');
var output = document.querySelector('pre');

input.oninput = function() {
    var lines = this.value.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/).filter(s => s.trim().length);
    // Strip the case count and array element counts:
    lines = lines.slice(1).filter( (s, i) => i % 2 ); 
    // Call function for each test case, returning array of booleans:
    var results = lines.map( line => hasMiddle(line.match(/[\d-]+/g).map(Number)));
    // Output results
    output.textContent = results.map( pos => pos ? 'YES' : 'NO' ).join('\n');
}
// Evaluate input immediately
input.oninput();
```

```html
Input:<br>
<textarea style="width:100%; height:120px">2 
3
 1 2 3

4
 1 2 3 3
</textarea>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you trincot,

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array once to find the sum. Declare two variables: sumLeft and sumRight. sumLeft should have an initial value of 0 and sumRight should be totalSum-arr[0].

Iterate over the array again and increment sumLeft by the (n-1) element and decrement sumRight by the nth element. Keep comparing the two variables to check if they equal each other. You cut your time complexity down to O(n)

The below code passed the test on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-array . The tricky part was setting up default responses for when the array length was 1. I will admit that @trincot 's answer was more efficient (n as opposed to 2n) for arrays containing only positive integers.

```
 function check(input) {
    var result = "NO";
    var sum=0;

     if(input.length == 1){
        console.log("YES");
        return;
     }

    input.map(function(data){
        sum=sum+(+data);
    })
    sumLeft=0;
    sumRight=sum-(+input[0]);

    for(var i=1;i<input.length-1;i++){
        sumLeft=sumLeft+(+input[i-1]);
        sumRight=sumRight-(+input[i])
        if(sumLeft==sumRight)
        {
            console.log("YES");
            return;
        }else if (sumLeft>sumRight) {  ///worked both with and without this optimization
            console.log("NO"); 
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("NO");
}



function processData(input) {

    //var lines = input.split("\r\n");
    var lines = input.split(/\r|\n/)
    for (var m = 2; m < lines.length; m = m + 2) {
        check(lines[m].split(" "));
    }
}
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function(input) {
    _input += input;
});
process.stdin.on("end", function() {
    processData(_input);
});
```

Comment: You'll want to increment the one and decrement the other by the *same* element

Comment: Actually no because its the elements to the left

Comment: Hi, I have modified as suggested but no luck.

Comment: If the array can only contain positive integers you can further optimize by stopping when sumLeft is greater than sumRight

Comment: Is it still a timing out issue?

Comment: Yes Lucas, still getting time out issue.

Comment: when I ran the code you posted I received a wrong answer on test case 6, did you not even get that far because of the timeout?

Comment: Code is passing for all test cases if we just return to condition if(input.length == 1)  without printing "YES".

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have a proper array one might do as follows

```js
var arr = [...Array(35)].map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*10)+1),
    sum = arr.reduce((p,c) => p+c),
   half = Math.floor(sum/2),
     ix;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  midix = arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => { (p+=c) < half ? p : !ix && (ix = i);
                                    return i < a.length - 1  ? p : ix;
                                  },0);
console.log("best possible item in the middle @ index", midix,": with value:",arr[midix]);
console.log("sums around midix:",
            arr.slice(0,midix)
               .reduce((p,c) => p+c),
            ":",
            arr.slice(midix+1)
               .reduce((p,c) => p+c));
```

Of course for randomly populated arrays as above, we can not always get a perfect middle index.